# Top level object name in knockout

Tags: c#, json, serialization, knockout.js

I am using JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize with knockout to serialize my viewmodel. The trouble is I am not getting a top level property name to use with the foreach binding. How do I do this?

My JSON looks like this:

```
widgets.apply([{"WidgetType":"ListWidget", "Items":[
    {"LinkText":"Product terms","Url":"http://bbc.co.uk"},
    {"LinkText":"Customer","Url":"http://bbc.co.uk"},    
    {"LinkText":"Reports","Url":"http://bbc.co.uk"}],"Title":"Actions"}]);
});
```

and my knockout looks like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Items" class="widget">
    <a data-bind="attr: { title: LinkText, href: Url }"></a>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

M

Comment: Other than putting `<a>` elements directly in a `<ul>` element?

Answer (score 1):

Two options spring to mind:

1) Use `$root`:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root -->
<h3 data-bind="text: WidgetType"></h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Items" class="widget">
    <li><a data-bind="attr: { title: LinkText, href: Url }">Link</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

2) Give yourself a top-level property name:

```
widgets.apply({
    TopLevelPropertyName: [
        {
            "WidgetType":"ListWidget",
            "Items": [
                {"LinkText":"Product terms","Url":"http://bbc.co.uk"},
                {"LinkText":"Customer","Url":"http://bbc.co.uk"},    
                {"LinkText":"Reports","Url":"http://bbc.co.uk"}
            ],
            "Title":"Actions"
        }
    ]
});

<!-- ko foreach: TopLevelPropertyName -->
<h3 data-bind="text: WidgetType"></h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Items" class="widget">
    <li><a data-bind="attr: { title: LinkText, href: Url }">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. I needed to use the name of the viewmodel as the root of my look:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: widget">...
```

Thanks for your answers.

M